# Listing files from directory

Tags: directory, ls

I have a question regarding directories. My homework question is this:

> Use metacharacters and the `ls -lL` command (with lower and upper case L) to list all filenames under the datafiles directory that contain a dot '.' with the letter 'f' or 'u' anywhere after the dot.

I know it begins `ls -lL`, but I'm not sure what else to put.

Comment: You can read the man page of ls, just type in your prompt `man ls`, there you can read about your **homework**. Just a tip: I think that the option your are looking for is `ls -ILa` . Greetings

Comment: Can you point us to your most recent class/lab material? Hopefully we can point out what you've missed.

Comment: Don't forget to hit our [tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) page after registering your account, so that you can edit your question and accept answer(s)!

Comment: Does `u` or `f` can appear untill a _first dot_ seen?  Like `u.file..f` what about Hidden files? `.a hidden file`

Comment: @k.Cyborg: I believe that you’re sending the OP on a wild goose chase.  The answer to this question cannot be found in the `ls` man page. Hint: if you learned about ``ls`` on Monday, you should look closely at your notes from last Thursday and Friday, and Tuesday.

Answer (score 2):

> filenames under the datafiles directory that contain a dot '.' with the letter 'f' or 'u' anywhere after the dot.

If I was to guess, it'd be something like:

```
ls -lL datafiles/*.*[fu]*
```

although the datafiles directory could be anywhere (else), and I find it a little odd that they're encouraging habitual use of the `-L` flag.

Comment: I personally can't remember the last time I used `-L` with `ls`...